# How to mapReduce() in Studio 3T/MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, studio3t

I recently started to work with MongoDB and I came across the mapReduce method. I understood theory behind it, but i'm having problem with practice, i'll try to explain: i'm using Studio 3T as IDE and I saw the 'add/edit stored functions' option by right-clicking DBs, i creted map and reduce functon with this option, but i don't know how to call them.

This is how I define map and reduce function:

[image]
[image]

and this is how i call them, receiving the ReferenceError.
[image]

**EDIT 1** : I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934829/mapreduce-in-mongodb), but it doesn't do what i'd like to do, he define functions in mongodb shell, i'd like to be able to define them in studio 3t and call them "when" i want to.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using IntelliShell (the smarter mongo shell equivalent in Studio 3T) for map-reduce functions, it would be simpler to use the dedicated Map-Reduce feature (full documentation [here](https://studio3t.com/whats-new/mongodb-map-reduce-easily-mongochef/)), which will spare you the task of defining, storing, and calling separate functions.

Comment: ye, I saw it but I need functions available "when" i want. I'll try to explain better: I'm doing a project for university where i store functions (procedures) in MongoDB, then call them from c# (visual studio in my case) with parameters introduced by user (i'll develop a simple GUI for users, something like windows' calculator). So i'd like to write functions easily, save them then be able to call them when i want in my code.